# Reading a .txt file and sorting into categories Python 3

Tags: python, list, class, python-3.x, file-io

I am trying to access data stored in a text file and sorting the data by specific lines in the text file.

Here is the data, text in `" "` is not included in the text file but for reference:

```
741258 "This is a student ID" 
CSF105 "This is a course module"
39 "This is a module mark"
CSF104
86
CSF102
71
CSF106
16
CSF103
3
CSF100
88
CSF101
50
123456
CSF100
50
CSF101
98
CSF102
74
CSF103
84
CSF104
65
CSF105
79
CSF106
100
```

I need to extract the Student ID then build a list of modules and marks based on that student ID and produce the average marks for that student, I am using Classes and methods to sort the data and if I input it directly via a function just using one set of data i.e.

```
id1 = Student("754412")
id1.addMark(Mark("CSF102", 90))
id1.addMark(Mark("CSF101", 80))
id1.addMark(Mark("CSF101", 42))
id1.addMark(Mark("CSF104", 90))
print(id1)
print("The Students average mark is: ", id1.calculateAverageMark())
```

It works.  How do I get python to read the lines and determine which is the next student ID in the list as to not continuously read after the last mark/module for the student?  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Presumably `CSF` marks a course line? E.g. after a course mark, when a line doesn't start with `CSF` there is a new student?

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the open file object and use `next()` to get a next line in the loop to read both course and course mark.

If a line does not start with `CSF` then it is assumed that we started reading a new student:

```
with open(inputfilename) as infh:
    student = Student(next(infh).strip())
    # auto-strip all lines
    infh = (l.strip() for l in infh)
    for line in infh:
        if line.startswith('CSF'):
            student.addMark(Mark(line, next(infh)))
        else:
            # new student, output information on the previous student first
            print(student)
            print("The Students average mark is: ", student.calculateAverageMark())
            student = Student(line)

    # last student info
    print(student)
    print("The Students average mark is: ", student.calculateAverageMark())
```

Comment: `file` is more readable than `infh`. To avoid repeating `.strip()`: `lines = (line.strip() for line in file)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `file` masks the built-in type object, and when you have another (writeable) file open `infh` is distinguisable from `outfh`.

Comment: There is `open`; you shouldn't use `file` directly in most cases. I don't see the second file in your example. I use `input_file`, `output_file` in such cases.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: there is `isinstance()` which only works with `file`, not `open`.

Comment: `file` *very* rarely needed in Python 2. It is gone in Python 3. OP uses Python 3. In general, I agree with you that you shouldn't shadow builtins but in this particular case (`file`) it is the rule that should be broken.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: you have a point that it is gone in Python 3. 'Rarely needed in Python 2' is a great reason not to mask the name in Stack Overflow answers which are being copied all over the place.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Still, my personal preference is to use a name that reflects the usage, and `file` is too generic for my taste.